# Using CDN with Liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, cdn

We are using CDN for our custom theme. Now we want to do same for all Liferay static resources(js,images,css and fonts). Has anyone done this before? We are planning to move whole `/html` of ROOT to CDN. But we faced some issues regarding `compass` from some css files which imports `compass`. What is the ideal scenario while uploading Liferay's static resources to CDN? Any help? We are using `cdn.host.http` in portal-ext.properties.

Answer (score 0):

Do not move resources from the webapp to the CDN! A lot of those things are not actual resources, but more of a ‘source’! For example, the css in the `ROOT/html` are actually SASS files and will not work if moved as is. The best solution is to use a Squid-like proxy to cache resources from the actual <del>tomcat</del> portal as they are requested.